# How do I manage my company's email services?

Tags: email, g-suite

I'm setting up my company's email with google apps and I would like to know how I manage all of the emails that deal with customer or automatically generated services, such as:

- support@example.com
- contact@example.com
- info@example.com
- etc.

I am just wondering what the best way to set these up would be. Do I create separate users for each and then forward them to one address (such as services@example.com); Do I just create a user name services@example.com and then give it nicknames for all of the other emails (support, contact, info, etc.); or is it best to just manage them all separately?

Just trying to get other people's opinions/experience on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on how your organization works with these addresses.

**If all those addresses are monitored by the same department,** then it would make sense to throw everything into one mailbox and use nicknames to route all addresses into it.

People would then log in to their own account, or to this "service" account. (Or they would log in to both at the same time, using two different browser windows.)

**If the addresses are monitored by different departments,** then I would set up an account for each department and use nicknames to route the relevant addresses to the suitable mailbox.

**If it's a one-person busines** then I would only use a single account and have it receive *everything*.

Comment: I like torbengb's answer with the following addition! If you are using auto responses and they are different for user than info, you will want to set up a different account for each one of them. They can still be forwarded to a central box. Also if you want to ANSWER people with the different names, you may want to set up separate accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create these emails separatly (ie. support, contact, etc), and then configure your outlook or whatever to receive the emails from these adresses all in the same place.

Comment: He did say they're using Google Apps, so Outlook or another local mail client may not be relevant...